# How can I get bash completion to sort files by create/modify date instead of alphabetically?

Tags: bash-completion

More often than not, I'm working with newer files.

So, is there a way to get bash completion to show newer ones first/last instead of sorting them alphabetically?

Comment: Please add what you have tried?

Comment: Nothing really. I go `ls <tab><tab>` and see files in the directory, but they're sorted alphabetically.